# GWT RPC call method in specific client

Tags: gwt, methods, client, call, rpc

first of all I want to call client metohd from server. If it's possible to call method in specific client via RPC (when other client send some data to server)? Especially I'm curious about GWT. I was thinking about creating something like list of client proxy on server but it's probably bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`GWT complier` only cares about code in client and shared package(`defined in *.gwt.xml under source tag`). It ignores everything used and referred in server packages. In fact you can create a separate `package` for your server layer as well by adding appropriate dependencies to your GWT webapp.

> so you can not call a method from `server package` to `client package`